# React, trigger one modal to open when another closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on implementing a modal which can open another modal.  I have a user sign up modal which has a "Add Contact" button.  Clicking this button triggers the "Add Contact Modal" to appear.

`AddContactModal` is an older component and is currently called in the `App.js` file right above the main `Routes` component.

```
<Router forceRefresh={!supportsHistory()}>
   <div className={appClassNames}>
     <Providers>
       <AddContactModal />
       <PhoneVerificationModal />
       <NavBar currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
       <div className="app-content">
           {Routes(actions)}
           <Footer />
       </div>
   </Providers>
 </div>
</Router>
```

The `Routes(actions)` renders most of the application. `AddContactModal` also has all of its functions declared in a global context file so it can be opened from anywhere in the application.

My new modal `SignUpModal` lives on a particular route and has all of its functions in a local hooks folder.

```
-src
--context
----addContactModalContext.js
--scenes
----Contacts
-------addContactModal.js
----SignUp
------signUpHooks.js
------signUpModal.js
```

Because of the structure used I can call the function to open my contact modal from my signup modal. However I cannot reopen the signup modal from the contact modal.

I have tried adding event listeners to the signup page to listen for the contact modal submit and I was not successfully.

I know I could restructure things but that would be a pretty large endeavor.

Hoping someone has some advice.  Ideally submitting the contact modal would trigger the sign up modal to open again ONLY when the user is on the sign up page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe handle some state for your submit in your context, so it can be heard with an useEffect in your other component and it handles showing up the modal you need.
Not sure if it would help but maybe it's a new idea.